# Why does importing httplib2 work on the command line, but not in Eclipse with PyDev?

Tags: python, python-3.x

[image: Screenshot]

As you can see ,I use windows command line running one line:

```
import httplib2
```

There is no error.

But when using Eclipse and PyDev, I got an error! And the version of Python is same. I did have two versions of python, 2.7.1 and 3.1.3, and my system path points to 2.7.1.

Who can explain this to me? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've called your script `http.py`. This shadows the `http` package in the stdlib. Rename your script.

Comment: Did you remove the .pyc file?

Comment: I don't know where is the .pyc file. I created a new file testhttp.py,copied all the contents,I can run it though the error tips are still there.(Unresolved import: httplib2
Unused import: httplib2)

Comment: you can see where your http.py was in your own screenshot, http.pyc would get made right next to it.